# Ruby, regex, sentences

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm currently building a code generator, which aims to generate boiler plate for me once I write the templates and/or translations, in whatever language I have to work with.

I have a problem with a regex in Ruby. The regex aims to select whatever is between `{{{` and `}}}`, so I can generate functions according to my needs.

My regex is currently :

```
/\{\{\{(([a-zA-Z]|\s)+)\}\}\}/m
```

My test data set is:

```
{{{Demande    aaa}}} => {{{tagadatsouintsouin    tutu}}}
```

The results are:

```
[["Demande aaa", "a"], ["tagadatsouintsouin tutu", "u"]]
```

Each time the regex picks the last character twice. That's not exactly what I want, I need something more like this:

```
/\{\{\{((\w|\W)+)\}\}\}/m
```

But this has a flaw too, the results are:

```
[["Demande aaa}}} => {{{tagadatsouintsouin tutu", "u"]]
```

Whereas, I wish to get:

```
[["Demande aaa"],["tagadatsouintsouin tutu"]]
```

How do I correct these regexes? I could use two sets of delimiters, but it won't teach me anything.

Edit :

All your regex run against my data sample, so you all got a point.

Regex may be overkill, and probably are overkill for my purpose.  So i have two questions.

First, do the regex keep the same exact indentation ? This should be able to handle whole functions.

Second, is there something fitter for that task ?

Detailled explanation of the purpose of this tool. I'm bored to write boiler plate code in php - symfony. So i wish to generate this according to templates.

My intent is to build some views, some controllers, and even parts of model this way.

Pratical example :  In my model, i wish to generate some functions according to the type of an object's attribute. For examples, i have functions displaying correctly money. So i need to build the corect function, according to my attribute, and then put in , inside m output file.

So there is some translations which themselves need translations.

So a fictive example :

```
{{{euro}}} => {{{ function getMyAttributeEuro()
 {
   return formating($this->get[[MyAttribute]]);
 } }}}
```

In order to stock my translations, should i use regex, like

I wish to build something a bit clever, so it can build most of the basic code with no bug. So i can work on interesting code.

Comment: Do you really wish to match *anything*  between `{{{` and `}}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one set of capturing parentheses too many.

```
/\{\{\{([a-zA-Z\s]+)\}\}\}/
```

Also, you don't need the `/m` modifier because there is no dot (`.`) in your regex whose behaviour would be affected by it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to:

```
data = '{{{Demande    aaa}}} => {{{tagadatsouintsouin    tutu}}}'
data.scan(/\{{3}(.+?)}{3}/).flatten.map{ |r| r.squeeze(' ') }
=> ["Demande aaa", "tagadatsouintsouin tutu"]
```

or:

```
data.scan(/\{{3}(.+?)}{3}/).flatten.map{ |r| [ r.squeeze(' ') ] }
=> [["Demande aaa"], ["tagadatsouintsouin tutu"]]
```

or:

```
data.scan(/\{{3}(.+?)}{3}/).map{ |r| [ r[0].squeeze(' ') ] }
=> [["Demande aaa"], ["tagadatsouintsouin tutu"]]
```

if you need the sub-arrays.

I'm not big on trying to everything possible inside the regex. I prefer to keep it short and sweet, then polish the output once I've found what I was looking for. It's a maintenance issue, because regex make my head hurt, and I stopped thinking of them as a macho thing years ago. Regex are a very useful tool, but too often they are seen as the answer to every problem, which they're not.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know,
>   I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.

-- [Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot

```
/\{\{\{([\w\W]+?)\}\}\}/
```

Added non-greedyness to your regex

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/RuMfHiVB8F) this seems to work

Answer (score 1):

You want non capturing groups `(?:...)`, but here is another way.

```
/\{\{\{(.*?)\}\}\}/m
```